# Any LaTeX formatting?

Tags: feature-request

Why can't I use LaTeX formatting on this site like I can on other stack exchange site ? More specifically, can I insert the degree symbol?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there's only *one* SE site that supports LaTeX and that's Math.  I don't even think that the LaTeX SE supports LaTeX formatting.

Comment: I don't think it is presently necessary here, HTML works. For the record the list of sites includes at least stats, math, cstheory and physics.

Comment: Aaronut: [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions) supports it too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would you need LaTeX for inserting a degree symbol? Just use the html entity: `&deg;`= °

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that I could do that, or how.

Comment: Also Alt+0176 (on Windows).

Comment: one less keystroke (old DOS) Alt+248 works for me

Answer (score 1):

Jeff has stated that MathJax is so large a chunk of javascript that it will **only** be made available on sites like [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions) where is is necessary. For instance we have [definitive word that Stack Overflow will not get MathJax support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4152/2509).